# Where can I find a general description of every single executable that comes with Windows?

Tags: windows, system-file

There are many executables, which one can see in the TaskManager. Sometimes some of them consume a bit of CPU power and I am curious what they are doing.

Comment: which version of windows do you use? There is probably no such a list published by Microsoft. Your best option to search the internet for single process names.

Comment: There are hundreds of system files what you want isn't realistic

Comment: If you want the executable file description for all executables in the windows path I have an answer. Please [edit] your question to clarify and we can think about reopening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How general? Executables usually have a description field associated with them. Some process monitoring software will display this field. I use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), a Task Manager replacement, which shows this and lot of other process info.

[image]

and it has a way to save as text. Kind of messy, with the tabs, but usable. [Fragment on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/uqTQ8uSD), [REDACTED] and [TRIMMED] is me.

(The items listed with "2TB" entries is an issue related to Control Flow Guard (CFG). Thanks, @JamieHanrahan)

Comment: Could you include an example?

Comment: Answer updated with image and link to text export. Note that not all tasks have descriptions, but the majority do.

Comment: You can find this information for most code files (exe, dll, sys, etc.) in the file Properties., Details tab.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Yeah, but that's more of a one-file-at-a-time thing and you'd need to match those files up with what is currently running.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a valid answer to the question, particularly as phrased in the title.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Then, perhaps, add it as an answer.

Comment: @Ouroborus: OT, but... the 2 TB VA allocations are due to a Windows 10 security technique called Control Flow Guard (CFG). See Alex Ionescu's blog post here: http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=300

Comment: Open a powershell command prompt and enter: `get-childitem c:\ -include *.exe -force  -recurse | foreach-object { "{0}\`t{1}" -f $_.FullName, [System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($_).FileDescription } >> exes.txt`  The result will be the complete file paths + descriptions in the file exes.txt. If you want just the file names (without paths), change "FullName" to "Name". Note that not all exes have descriptions.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Window 8 here, but probably the same thing. Windows 7 at home so that explains the difference. Thank you much for this insite!

Comment: I accept the answer. It also seems to work with the standard Task Manager. Nevertheless, a process I was interested in, is not running in my system, so I am unable to check it.